# When to use the equals sign in a Scala method declaration?

Tags: scala

With equals sign:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("Hello!")
  }
}
```

Without equals sign:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello!")
  }
}
```

Both of the above programs execute the same way. In the blog post *[Things I do not like in Scala](http://www.francolombardo.net/things-i-do-not-like-in-scala_post-69.html)* I read that when the equals sign are missing, the method will return `Unit` (same as Java's `void`), so methods that return a value must use the equals sign. But methods that don't return a value can be written either way.

What is the best practice for using the equals sign in Scala methods that don't return a value?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I actually disagree pretty strongly with Daniel. I think the non-equal syntax should *never* be used. If your method is being exposed as an API and you're worried about accidentally returning the wrong type, add an explicit type annotation:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello!")
    123
  }
}
```

The non-equal syntax is shorter and might look "cleaner", but I think it just adds the possibility of confusion. I have sometimes forgotten to add an equal sign and believed my method was returning a value when actually it was returning Unit. Because the non-equal and equal-with-inferred-type syntaxes are so visually similar, it's easy to miss this problem.

Even though it costs me a little more work, I prefer the explicit type annotations when they matter (namely, exposed interfaces).

Comment: I like this approach, it's more explicit and thus more clear to the reader.

Comment: Apparently that is now the recommended style (http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#procedure_syntax) so I'm changing this to be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree with that too, I think the syntax without the = should be removed altogether from the language

Comment: Martin Odersky in his keynote "Scala with Style" said that it was a historical mistake. He had to add this syntax (without =) so that he can hide "Unit" from Java developers so that they don't get confused. Also he mentioned that it will be removed in the future.

Comment: Is there any way to WARN if equals sign was forgotten in method definition? As a compiler option, for example, or in any source analysis tool?

Comment: I _really_ can't see the benefit of this. When I write a method, the first thing I think of after parameter parenthesis is: is this going to return something? If yes, then specify the type followed by '=', else '{'. This new style just means more code for something that doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is because `Unit { ... }` is a type refinement, so `def f(): Unit { ... }` declares an abstract method returning `Unit { ... }`.

Answer (score 42):

UPDATE: as of Scala-2.10, using equals sign is preferred. Old answer:

Methods which return `Unit` should *always* use the non-equals syntax.  This avoids potential mistakes in implementation carrying over into the API.  For example, you could have accidentally done something like this:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("Hello!")
    123
  }
}
```

Trivial example of course, but you can see how this might be a problem.  Because the last expression does *not* return `Unit`, the method itself will have a return type other than `Unit`.  This is exposed in the public API, and might cause other problems down the road.  With the non-equals syntax, it doesn't matter what the last expression is, Scala fixes the return type as `Unit`.

It's also two characters cleaner.  :-)  I also tend to think that the non-equals syntax makes the code just a little easier to read.  It is more obvious that the method in question returns `Unit` rather than some useful value.

On a related note, there is an analogous syntax for abstract methods:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(s: String)
}
```

The method `bar` has signature `String=>Unit`.  Scala does this when you omit the type annotation on an abstract member.  Once again, this is cleaner, and (I think) easier to read.

Comment: Not using the equals sign is also the recommendation in the Scala Style Guide: http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/types/inference/void_methods.html

Comment: I wrote that bit, so you should probably keep that in mind when you weigh the reference.  :-)

Comment: LoL, so I described this little exchange to my girlfriend, except due to my poor enunciation "bit" came out as "bitch". Needless to say, comedy ensued.

Comment: ScalaDays 2013, Martin Odersky, [Keynote - Scala with Style chapter 45](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c1994ae4b0d38b54f4621b/chapter45/about): procedure declaration (non-equals syntax) should be avoided.

Comment: Official style guide does not recommend this anymore: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#procedure_syntax

Answer (score 12):

You *must* use equals sign in call declarations except the definitions returning Unit.

In this latter case, you *may* forgo the equals sign. This syntax may be deprecated, though, so it's best avoided. Using equals sign and declaring the return type will always work.

Comment: Books, mailing list, source code. By the way, since that time it became clear that the latter syntax is unlikely to be deprecated, and it is favored by many.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#function_values Looks like the types style guide indicates using = all the time anyway.

Answer (score 4):

For methods, [Scala Style Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html) recommends the equals syntax as opposed to procedure syntax

> > **Procedure Syntax**
> >
> > Avoid the procedure syntax, as it tends to be confusing for very little gain in brevity.

```
// don't do this
def printBar(bar: Baz) {
  println(bar)
}
// write this instead
def printBar(bar: Bar): Unit = {
  println(bar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing : imagine the last statement of a method that should return Unit does not return Unit. Using the non-equal syntax is then very convenient, I hope this will not be deprecated as I see several use case for it

Answer (score 0):

As time as progressed the default style has changed, and this has been mentioned in many of the comments to answers, it is recommended in the [official style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#functions) to use the `=` syntax for function declarations.

Comment: The link you provided only talks about functions, not procedures (i.e. functions which return Unit).

Comment: You're right, @EskoLuontola, Sorry about that, I probably copied the wrong link out of one of many tabs I had open, it's been updated.

Answer (score 0):

for method that dont have a return value,  a way to express such methods is leaving out the result type and the
equals sign, following the method with a block enclosed in curly braces. In
this form, the method looks like a procedure, a method that is executed only
for its side effects.