# scala: 'def foo = {1}' vs 'def foo {1}'

Tags: scala, methods

what is going on in each of these forms of defining foo?:

```
scala> def foo = {1}
foo: Int

scala> foo
res2: Int = 1
```

But:

```
scala> def foo {1}
foo: Unit

scala> foo

scala>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See also [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration) on SO:

> *In Scala if a method declaration does not have an equal sign before its body, the compiler infers that the result type will be* `Unit`

Basically declaring a function with no `=` means that the function returns `Unit` and the compiler inserts a `()` for you at the end. A function which should return a non-`Unit` value **must** be declared with the `=` notation (although of course the compiler can infer the return-type from the expression's type).

Answer (score 2):

found this in http://anyall.org/scalacheat/:

```
//[bad!] 
def f(x: Int) { x*x } //hidden error: without = it's a Unit-returning proc; causes havoc
```