# scala - def with and without =

Tags: scala, function

Is there a difference between the two following..

```
scala> def foo() = {}
foo: ()Unit

scala> def foo() {}
foo: ()Unit
```

They seem to be the same.
Is there a reason both are supported?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661817/scala-def-foo-1-vs-def-foo-1

Comment: The latter form can only be used for defining functions that return unit. The first is used for all other functions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def foo() {}
```

is equivalent to (and enforces)

```
def foo(): Unit = {}
```

while

```
def foo() = {}
```

will apply type infering to determine the result type from the body of the method.

So, with the first two options, `Unit` is the only allowed return type, while in the third, the return type depends on the implementation.

Comment: Aaah, fantastic explanation. I didn't know return types could be inferred, thanks Mef!

Comment: It's one of the many awesome things of the Scala language :-) It is worth noting that for methods/functions, at least those of your public API, the return type should still be displayed to be nice to readers of your code/API.

Comment: @SeanConnolly: Indeed, in most circumstances return types can be inferred by the compiler (the cannot if it is directly recursive). But it is often not a good idea to rely on it. There are two reasons not rely on type inference for methods: 1) Explicit result types have documentation value; 2) Inferred types may be narrower or more complex than you like. An example of (2) is returning a `HashMap`. You probably don't want your API contract to specify such a specific type and absent an explicit return type annotation, you'll be tied to that concrete type lest you make a breaking change.

Comment: Good point @RandallSchulz, cheers!