# why does scala use = operator while defining function

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I have worked on java. defining of function in scala by using = operator does not make sense for me.

```
def abc(a:Int,b:Int):Int = 
    a+b
```

can anybody explain? in the above code, why i had to use = operator.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661817/scala-def-foo-1-vs-def-foo-1) for more information about the difference of using or not using = in method declaration.

Answer (score 7):

I believe there are many reasons. Just some of them:

1) [uniform access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle):

```
val abc: Int = 5 //value
def abc: Int = 5 //factory
```

Note that such `def abc` can be implemented with `val abc` inside successor:

```
trait Interface {
  def abc: Int //factory (reader)
}

object Implementation extends Interface {
  val abc: Int = 5 //singleton
}
```

Some advanced examples: [Why it's impossible to override `var` with `def` in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623074/why-its-impossible-to-override-var-with-def-in-scala/27624879#27624879)

2) functions are just named lambda's:

```
val abc = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b //lambda assigned to abc value
def abc (a:Int, b:Int): Int = a + b //abc method, that could be converted to lambda/function with eta-expansion: "abc _"
```

The syntactic difference between first and second one is just position of braces, so they are quite similar.

3) that function actually returns value, you might think of the `a + b` block independently from function definition, so then:

```
def abc ...: Int = {
   val z = a + b
   z
}
```

is almost like

```
val abc: Int = {
  val z = a + b
  z
}
```

But `a` and `b` are unknown, so we need to describe them too:

```
def abc(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  val z = a + b
  z
}
```

Otherwise, if your method doesn't return anything, you can omit `=` sign:

```
def abc(a: Int, b: Int) {
  println(a + b)
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def abc(a: Int, b: Int): Unit = {
  println(a + b)
}
```

Where `Unit` (inhabited type with only one possible value, so it contains no information) roughly means that no value was returned.

See also [official doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html) and [language spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html)

Comment: Unit is certainly inhabited. It's Nothing that's not.

Answer (score 3):

This approach enhances the functional aspect of programming, where functions are no different than other data types.

e.g. In Scala

```
val number = 10
val function = (a:Int, b:Int) => a + b
```

Here, both the values `number` and `function` are immutable variables.  Only difference is their types.  `number` is of type `Int`, while `function` is of type `(Int, Int) => Int`

This enables functions to be treated just like Data and be passed around like other variables.  This enhances into concepts like [Higher Order Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) which can accept and return function values as opposed to literal values.  As @dk14 mentioned, it's about uniform access.

Answer (score 1):

There is one reason I know why scala uses = in method declaration is:

To return any value from method definition ,= has to be used or it cant return any value even if there is a return statement in method.

For Eg: look at below two code snippets:

```
def method1()
{
  val a=1
  return a
}

def method2()=
{
  val a=1
  return a
}
```

`method1` return type is always unit even if it returns some values
whereas `method2` returns value a .

Comment: The last sentence here is wrong.  method1 returns a unit, method2 returns a.type