# Odd behaviour with scala method syntax

Tags: scala

I hit a bit of a quirk of scala's syntax I don't really understand

```
object Board {
   def getObjectAt(x:Int, y:Int):Placeable = return locations(x)(y)
}
```

works fine. But

```
object Board {
   def getObjectAt(x:Int, y:Int):Placeable {
      return locations(x)(y)
   }
}
```

returns the error

```
Board.scala:8: error: illegal start of declaration
return locations(x)(y)
```

I found some stuff that says the second form convinces the scala compiler you're trying to specify an expansion to the return type `Placeable`. Is there a way I can fix this, or should I just avoid specifying a return type here?

Comment: BTW the "return" keyword is superfluous and can be omitted. In the absence of an explicit return statement Scala returns the last value computed by the method. Recommended style is to avoid explicit methods (especially multiple returns).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use the equals sign in a Scala method declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just about the function syntax.

If your function has a return value, you'll always define it as an *equation* (using *=*), even if a block of computations follows:

```
object Board {
   def getObjectAt(x:Int, y:Int):Placeable = {
      return locations(x)(y)
   }
}
```

The notation

```
def func(...) { ...
```

is shorthand for return-type `Unit`, i.e. a function *without* return value.