# Scala methods with = (equality sign)

Tags: function, scala, procedure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use the equals sign in a Scala method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration)

What's the difference between

```scala
def x {}
```

and

```scala
def x = {}
```

?

Comment: Definitely! Thanks for providing the link, @om-nom-nom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def x {}` is called "procedure" style, it is shorthand for `def x: Unit = {}` (quoting Viktor Klang from [this post](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/835#issuecomment-10210090)).