# Using = in Unit methods

Tags: scala

I'm a bit confused  about the Scala's recommended style of using the equal sign in `Unit` methods, which one is recommended?

```
 def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
  val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
    try {
     op(writer)
    } finally {
     writer.close()
    }
 }
```

or

```
 def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit) = {
  val writer = new PrintWriter(file)
    try {
     op(writer)
    } finally {
     writer.close()
    }
 }
```

Comment: yep, the answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/944791/618089) is pretty complete. If you do not intend to return results, prefer then notation **without** equal, or at least make it explicit that you do not return anything if you really want to use the =.  `def withPrintWriter(file: File, op: PrintWriter => Unit): Unit = {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are strong opinions on both sides of the aisle, and no answer based in cognitive science for picking a style, aside from "whichever is easier on your eyes."

Usually, someone will say that one style jumps out at them and says, "I don't return anything useful."

However, there is a [ticket to deprecate procedure syntax](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605).

The fact that at ticket was opened or that Odersky sees the feature as subject to future deprecation is not definitive, of course.

Possibly, the debate evolves into: If I define a procedure, should I always specify the `Unit` result type?  And the answer is probably yes.  As a rule, you want to avoid inferring useless things.

But isn't it a hassle adding `: Unit` all the time?  Yes, because procedures should stick out like the sore thumb they are.  When all you have is a hammer, you always wind up with a sore thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, initially it is a bit confusing.
I prefer using the Thumb rule like

If you are returning a value from a method, you may assign the return value to some other resource - Hence use "="

If you are not returning any value, you might just be computing/storing something or printing somethig - Hence forget about the "=".