# Compilation Error : 'value foreach is not a member of Unit'

Tags: scala

Hi Given below is the code. The function `Split_line` returns an Array. I suppose the value `splitted` should be of type `Array`. But is considered as `Unit` by the Compiler. What am I doing wrong here?

```
object Main {

  def Split_line(line: String){
    line.split("\\|\\|")    
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val splitted = Split_line("This is a line || hi ")
    //***I am getting error here : 'value foreach is not a member of Unit'
    splitted.foreach(println) 
  }

}
```

Comment: You miss an `=`. It should be `def splitLine(line:String) = {`. Besides that, I would advise to always put the return type of the function, typically to avoid this kind of errors. It's also a good practice, IMO. Closing as typographical error.

Comment: @AlexisC. has it right - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration for more on that.  In the future, please include actual text of your code in a code block, so we can easily copy and paste to try it ourselves, rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax always denotes a function returning unit. Use `def Split_line(line: String) = {` (with an equals) or better yet, if you are unsure, declare the return type explicitly: `def Split_line(line: String): Seq[String] = {`

DO note that there are even plans to remove that syntax altogether at some point: ["Procedure syntax is dropped in favor of always defining functions with ="](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/roadmap-next/#scala-don-giovanni).

Comment: Using only `|` did not work for me. Got to have \\ to make it work. `|` looks like is part of regex so have to use \\ to make it work

Comment: oh, true, that one was a regexp and not a string separator! fine, edited :-)