# Why return type for func1 is Unit whereas for func2 is Int ?

Tags: scala

I notice the = sign, but what's the actual difference here? Can somebody please explain?

//Func1

> def func1(x: Int, op: Int => Int){
>       op(x)
>   }

func1: (x: Int, op: Int => Int)Unit

//Func2

> def func2(x: Int, op: Int => Int) = {
>       op(x)
>   }

func2: (x: Int, op: Int => Int)Int

Comment: Hi Sunny, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to provide better formatted questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use the equals sign in a Scala method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944111/when-to-use-the-equals-sign-in-a-scala-method-declaration)

Comment: That _is_ "the actual difference".

Answer (score 0):

In scala, when you use "=" sign in a def, it will return something. 
So in your first function, you did not use = sign therefore the return type will be Unit(void in java).

For the second function, it return Int is because in Scala you can do something like this :

```
def sum(x:Int, y:Int) = {
    z:Int = x + y
    z
}

println(sum(3, 5))

//output = 8
```

Despite without using the word **return z**, it will still return the last variable in the function. Therefore the second function will return Int, which long form looks something like this:

```
def func2(x: Int, op: Int => Int):Int = {
    op(x) //this is the last value and it will be returned
}
```

The missing = sign will always return Unit (void in java)